# Sum elements of the list in Jinja 2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have list in Jinja2 that contain dicts in itself. Something like

```
items = [{'name':'name1', 'points':5}, {'name':'name2', 'points':7}, 
 {'name':'name3', 'points':2}, {'name':'name4', 'points':11}]
```

What I need is to get sum of all **points** and to print it somewhere later.

Currently what I got is:

```
{% set points = 0 -%}
{% for single_item in items -%}
    {% set points = points + single_item["points"] -%}
    {{points}}
{% endfor %}
{{ points }}
```

Result is: 5 12 14 25 0

Is there any way that I can get that **points** outside of loop has value **25** (last value from the loop)?

Comment: That sort of logic belongs in the controller, not the template. Preprocess your data accordingly, and pass `items` as tell as `total` to the template.

Comment: @LukasGraf Maybe you should post that as an answer ?

Comment: @LukasGraf I agree with you totally, but in my case, it would make big mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to make it work, although solution is not elegant, but it is working:

```
{% set points = [0] -%}
{% for single_item in items -%}
    {% if points.append(points.pop()+ single_item["points"]) -%}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ points }}
```

**points** will be array with just one element that has sum.

It can be also done with included **do** extension, and that would replace {% if %} line.

Comment:  This is not the best answer

Answer (score 52):

Jinja2 includes a sum filter which will do this for you:

```
{{ items | sum(attribute='points') }}
```

See documentation here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#jinja-filters.sum

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Cleaner than the accepted answer but still does work as it should

Answer (score 4):

That sort of logic should usually go in the controller, not the template (separating logic from presentation). Preprocess your data accordingly, and pass items as well as total to the template:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template(open('index.html').read())

items = [{'name': 'name1', 'points': 5},
         {'name': 'name2', 'points': 7},
         {'name': 'name3', 'points': 2},
         {'name': 'name4', 'points': 11}]

total = sum([i['points'] for i in items])

print template.render(items=items, total=total)
```

**`index.html`**:

```
<table>

{% for item in items %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.points }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>

<strong>Total:</strong>{{ total }}
```

For details on the expression `sum([i['points'] for i in items])` see [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Although this is good answer, and I know it can be done this way, for my case it won't work well. Will have several dictionaries with supporting values, and have total mess of code. I think I've found a way how to do this, need to test it bit more, and if it is working, will post answer.

Comment: Then you probably need to refactor your code. Can you edit your question to include an example of your code and several dictionaries?

Answer (score -1):

Found on: https://linuxtut.com/en/129012d5539a8724556d/

Solution 2: Use namespace
<2019/12/21: From na90ya> It seems that variables are preserved when using namespace objects introduced in 2.10 of jinja2. (Reference material [1])

count_test3.j2

```
{%- set ns = namespace(cnt=1) -%}
{%- for i in range(3) -%}
{%- set ns.cnt = ns.cnt + 1 -%}
{{ ns.cnt }}
{% endfor -%}
result : {{ ns.cnt }}
```

But i didn't try it yet...